# Broken packages after Ubuntu 18.04 upgrade

Tags: apt, package-management, upgrade, 18.04

Recently I have upgraded `Ubuntu 16` to `Ubuntu 18`. Everything works looks beautiful then earlier as well as working fine. However, I am not able to install or remove any package. I did research on multiple answer on this forum. But none of the solutions work for me. Here are the steps which I have performed.

```
$ sudo apt autoremove
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt --fix-broken install' to correct these.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 imagemagick-6.q16 : Breaks: libmagickcore-dev (< 8:6.9.2.10+dfsg-2~) but 8:6.7.7.10-6ubuntu3.12 is installed
 libmagick++-6.q16-dev : Breaks: libmagick++-dev (< 8:6.8.3.10-1~)
 libmagick++-dev : Depends: libmagickwand-dev (= 8:6.7.7.10-6ubuntu3.12) but it is not installed
 libmagickcore-6.q16-dev : Breaks: libmagickcore-dev (< 8:6.8.3.10-1~) but 8:6.7.7.10-6ubuntu3.12 is installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt --fix-broken install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

As per suggestion in output, I execute the next command :

```
$ sudo apt --fix-broken install
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Correcting dependencies... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  gnome-keyring-pkcs11:i386 gstreamer1.0-nice hardening-includes icc-profiles-free imagemagick-common libaccount-plugin-google libaether-java libamd2.2.0 libantlr4-runtime-java
  libapache2-mod-php libapache2-mod-php7.0 libapparmor-perl libappstream3 libasm3-java libasm4-java libasync-http-client-java libautodie-perl libavcodec53 libavformat53 libavutil51
  libbatik-java libbind9-90 libblas3gf libchamplain-gtk-0.12-0 libclassworlds-java libcloog-isl4 libclutter-gst-2.0-0 libcodenarc-groovy-java libcolamd2.8.0 libcolorhug1
  libcommons-beanutils-java libcommons-collections4-java libcommons-compress-java libcommons-configuration-java libcommons-digester-java libcommons-httpclient-java
  libcommons-jexl2-java libcommons-jxpath-java libcommons-net2-java libcommons-vfs-java libdbd-mysql-perl libdbi-perl libdns100 libdoxia-core-java libdoxia-java libeasymock-java
  libefivar0 libexiv2-12 libfontbox-java libfop-java libfwup0 libfwupd1 libgadu3 libgcrypt11:i386 libgegl-0.2-0 libgeronimo-ejb-3.2-spec-java libgeronimo-jpa-2.0-spec-java
  libgeronimo-osgi-support-java libgeronimo-validation-1.0-spec-java libgif4 libgif4:i386 libgmetrics-groovy-java libgnuinet-java libgnujaf-java libgnumail-java libgnutls-openssl27
  libgnutls26:i386 libgphoto2-port10 libgphoto2-port10:i386 libgraphviz-dev libgstreamer-plugins-base0.10-0:i386 libgstreamer0.10-0:i386 libgtkspell3-3-0 libgvc6-plugins-gtk
  libgweather-3-6 libhud2 libilmbase6 libisc95 libisccc90 libisccfg90 libisl10 libisl15 libitext1-java libjackrabbit-java libjaffl-java libjasper-dev libjavascriptcoregtk-1.0-0
  libjctools-java libjetty-extra libjetty-extra-java libjetty-java libjffi-java libjffi-jni libjnr-constants-java libjnr-ffi-java libjnr-posix-java libjnr-x86asm-java
  libjson-c2:i386 liblept4 liblinear1 liblwres90 libmagick++5 libmagickcore-dev libmagickcore5 libmagickcore5-extra libmagickwand5 libmaven-ant-tasks-java libmaven-archiver-java
  libmaven-scm-java libmaven2-core-java libmockobjects-java libmodello-java libmx4j-java libmysqlclient18:i386 libmysqlclient20 libnet-daemon-perl libnetty-java libopenexr6
  libopenraw1 libosgi-foundation-ee-java libp11-kit-gnome-keyring libp11-kit-gnome-keyring:i386 libpackagekit-glib2-16 libparboiled-java libpegdown-java libplexus-ant-factory-java
  libplexus-archiver-java libplexus-bsh-factory-java libplexus-build-api-java libplexus-classworlds2-java libplexus-cli-java libplexus-i18n-java libplexus-interactivity-api-java
  libplexus-io-java libpng12-0:i386 libpoppler-qt4-4 libpoppler44 libprocps3 libprotobuf-c1 libprotobuf8 libprotoc8 libqt5opengl5 libqt5organizer5 libqtwebkit4 libraw9 libsaxon-java
  libschroedinger-1.0-0 libservlet2.5-java libservlet3.0-java libsisu-guice-java libsisu-ioc-java libsnappy-java libsnappy-jni libspice-client-gtk-3.0-4 libspring-aop-java
  libspring-context-java libspring-expression-java libspring-instrument-java libsub-identify-perl libsystemd-login0 libterm-readkey-perl libtesseract3 libtinyxml2.6.2
  libtomcat7-java libtxc-dxtn-s2tc0 libtxc-dxtn-s2tc0:i386 libufe-xidgetter0 libumfpack5.4.0 libunity-action-qt1 libustr-1.0-1 libva1 libvpx1 libvpx3 libvpx3:i386 libwagon-ftp-java
  libwagon-java libwagon2-java libwebkitgtk-1.0-0 libwebpmux1 libwxbase2.8-0 libwxgtk2.8-0 libxbean-java libxdot4 libxmlgraphics-commons-java libxtables10 linux-headers-3.13.0-156
  linux-headers-3.13.0-156-generic linux-image-3.13.0-156-generic linux-image-extra-3.13.0-156-generic odbcinst odbcinst1debian2 oxideqt-codecs p11-kit-modules:i386 pgdg-keyring
  pidgin-data plainbox-provider-checkbox plainbox-provider-resource-generic python-certifi python-distlib python-pyatspi python-requests python3-pycurl
  qtdeclarative5-accounts-plugin qtdeclarative5-localstorage-plugin qtdeclarative5-unity-action-plugin signon-keyring-extension signon-plugin-password signon-ui snapd-login-service
  tesseract-ocr-equ ubuntu-ui-toolkit-theme unixodbc wine-gecko2.21 wine-gecko2.21:i386 wine-mono0.0.8 wine1.6-amd64 wine1.6-i386:i386
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove them.
The following additional packages will be installed:
  libmagick++-dev libmagickcore-dev
The following packages will be upgraded:
  libmagick++-dev libmagickcore-dev
2 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
3 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 0 B/2,780 B of archives.
After this operation, 6,226 kB disk space will be freed.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] Y
(Reading database ... 1227136 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../libmagick++-dev_8%3a6.9.7.4+dfsg-16ubuntu6.3_all.deb ...
dpkg-query: no packages found matching libmagick++-dev:all
dpkg-query: package 'libmagick++-dev' is not installed
Use dpkg --info (= dpkg-deb --info) to examine archive files,
and dpkg --contents (= dpkg-deb --contents) to list their contents.
dpkg-maintscript-helper: error: file '/usr/share/doc/libmagick++-dev' not owned by package 'libmagick++-dev:all'
dpkg-query: package 'libmagick++-dev' is not installed
Use dpkg --info (= dpkg-deb --info) to examine archive files,
and dpkg --contents (= dpkg-deb --contents) to list their contents.
dpkg-maintscript-helper: error: file '/usr/share/doc/libmagick++-dev/NEWS.Debian.gz' not owned by package 'libmagick++-dev:all'
dpkg-query: package 'libmagick++-dev' is not installed
Use dpkg --info (= dpkg-deb --info) to examine archive files,
and dpkg --contents (= dpkg-deb --contents) to list their contents.
dpkg-maintscript-helper: error: file '/usr/share/doc/libmagick++-dev/changelog.Debian.gz' not owned by package 'libmagick++-dev:all'
dpkg-query: package 'libmagick++-dev' is not installed
Use dpkg --info (= dpkg-deb --info) to examine archive files,
and dpkg --contents (= dpkg-deb --contents) to list their contents.
dpkg-maintscript-helper: error: file '/usr/share/doc/libmagick++-dev/copyright' not owned by package 'libmagick++-dev:all'
dpkg-maintscript-helper: error: directory '/usr/share/doc/libmagick++-dev' contains files not owned by package libmagick++-dev:all, cannot switch to symlink
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/libmagick++-dev_8%3a6.9.7.4+dfsg-16ubuntu6.3_all.deb (--unpack):
 new libmagick++-dev package pre-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 1
Preparing to unpack .../libmagickcore-dev_8%3a6.9.7.4+dfsg-16ubuntu6.3_all.deb ...
dpkg-query: no packages found matching libmagickcore-dev:all
dpkg-query: package 'libmagickcore-dev' is not installed
Use dpkg --info (= dpkg-deb --info) to examine archive files,
and dpkg --contents (= dpkg-deb --contents) to list their contents.
dpkg-maintscript-helper: error: file '/usr/share/doc/libmagickcore-dev' not owned by package 'libmagickcore-dev:all'
dpkg-query: package 'libmagickcore-dev' is not installed
Use dpkg --info (= dpkg-deb --info) to examine archive files,
and dpkg --contents (= dpkg-deb --contents) to list their contents.
dpkg-maintscript-helper: error: file '/usr/share/doc/libmagickcore-dev/NEWS.Debian.gz' not owned by package 'libmagickcore-dev:all'
dpkg-query: package 'libmagickcore-dev' is not installed
Use dpkg --info (= dpkg-deb --info) to examine archive files,
and dpkg --contents (= dpkg-deb --contents) to list their contents.
dpkg-maintscript-helper: error: file '/usr/share/doc/libmagickcore-dev/changelog.Debian.gz' not owned by package 'libmagickcore-dev:all'
dpkg-query: package 'libmagickcore-dev' is not installed
Use dpkg --info (= dpkg-deb --info) to examine archive files,
and dpkg --contents (= dpkg-deb --contents) to list their contents.
dpkg-maintscript-helper: error: file '/usr/share/doc/libmagickcore-dev/copyright' not owned by package 'libmagickcore-dev:all'
dpkg-maintscript-helper: error: directory '/usr/share/doc/libmagickcore-dev' contains files not owned by package libmagickcore-dev:all, cannot switch to symlink
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/libmagickcore-dev_8%3a6.9.7.4+dfsg-16ubuntu6.3_all.deb (--unpack):
 new libmagickcore-dev package pre-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/libmagick++-dev_8%3a6.9.7.4+dfsg-16ubuntu6.3_all.deb
 /var/cache/apt/archives/libmagickcore-dev_8%3a6.9.7.4+dfsg-16ubuntu6.3_all.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Comment: repeat this `sudo apt autoremove` again!

Comment: I have tried it so many times

Comment: I suspect there is something wrong with your sources - eg. I looked https://packages.ubuntu.com/bionic/libmagickcore-dev and it shows 8:6.9.7.4+dfsg-16ubuntu6.3 but your rule says "< 8:6.9.2.10+dfsg-2~" where the correct rule for `libmagickcore-6.q16-3 (>= 8:6.9.6.8)` https://packages.ubuntu.com/bionic/imagemagick-6.q16 so you have non-Ubuntu sources, or you have `apt-mark` blocks or something else in the way. Most likely your issues is non-Ubuntu sources.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I have tried below commands as per online forums helps, but none of the below commands works :

```
sudo apt-get clean
sudo apt-get autoclean
sudo apt-get autoremove
sudo apt-get -f install
sudo apt-get upgrade
sudo apt-get --purge remove package_name
```

After spending almost whole day, I found one suggestion from one of the answer from this forum. So, I removed all the mentioned broken package information one by one from file named `/var/lib/dpkg/status`.

I know, this is very tedious process. But this is the only things works for me.

Comment: I looked https://packages.ubuntu.com/bionic/libmagickcore-dev and it shows 8:6.9.7.4+dfsg-16ubuntu6.3 but your rule says "< 8:6.9.2.10+dfsg-2~" where the correct rule for libmagickcore-6.q16-3 (>= 8:6.9.6.8) https://packages.ubuntu.com/bionic/imagemagick-6.q16 so you have non-Ubuntu sources, or you have apt-mark blocks or something else in the way. Your answer implies it was `apt-mark` holds you had made, forgotten about, and not used `apt-mark show` to view then unset in order to allow upgrade. You manually did what the unhold would have achieved...  (a guess, we can't know anymore)

Comment: I did `sudo mv /var/lib/dpkg/status /var/lib/dpkg/_status && touch /var/lib/dpkg/status && sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade`

Comment: @ryanjdillon You should really post this comment as an answer. Simple command with a backup and worked perfectly

Comment: @Tofandel I just added it as an answer :)

Answer (score 2):

**Backup your status file**... Generally speaking, don't just delete things from `/var/` or other important places.

```
sudo mv /var/lib/dpkg/status /var/lib/dpkg/status.bak
```

**Create a new empty file**

```
touch /var/lib/dpkg/status
```

**Run an update and then upgrade**

```
sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade
```

---

**Or... in one line**:

```
sudo mv /var/lib/dpkg/status /var/lib/dpkg/_status && touch /var/lib/dpkg/status && sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade
```